# MYSQL insert update - on duplicate key update - getting error

Tags: php, mysql

I getting error "Query error!" with this code:

```
$result = $connection->query("INSERT INTO EMP_TBLE (NAME, AGE, CATEGORY, UPDATE_COUNT) VALUES('$NAME', '$AGE', $CAT, 1
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE UPDATE_COUNT = UPDATE_COUNT + 1"));
echo "<br>".$result;die;
```

I also check different example like this example was running success but I found error in above code for my demo project.

Comment: Where do you get `$NAME` and `$AGE` etc from? If these are from user input, be careful about SQL injection. You should be using parameter binding here.

Comment: at first you should use NAME with backticks ```NAME```

Comment: Print your query and post it into the question. See what you are running. Most probably, you'll find the error yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closing brace for `VALUES` is missing. There is also a non-needed brace at the end of your code line.

Please change

```
$result = $connection->query("INSERT INTO EMP_TBLE (NAME, AGE, CATEGORY, UPDATE_COUNT) VALUES('$NAME', '$AGE', $CAT, 1 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE UPDATE_COUNT = UPDATE_COUNT + 1"));
```

to

```
$result = $connection->query("INSERT INTO EMP_TBLE (NAME, AGE, CATEGORY, UPDATE_COUNT) VALUES('$NAME', '$AGE', $CAT, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE UPDATE_COUNT = UPDATE_COUNT + 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you did not close the parentesis in the right place:

```
$result = $connection->query("INSERT INTO EMP_TBLE (NAME, AGE, CATEGORY, 
UPDATE_COUNT) VALUES('$NAME', '$AGE', $CAT, 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE UPDATE_COUNT = UPDATE_COUNT + 1");
```

Also... you should at least escape all the variables before concatenating in queries like this to avoid SQL injection